# C program prints strange character

Tags: c, printing, char

When I run this program it prints a strange character in the terminal. Can someone tell me what that is?

```
int main(){
    char x=1;
    printf("%c\n",x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you think it should print?

Comment: ASCII code 1 is the start-of-heading character (which is unprintable/results in weirdness on stdout). I imagine that you want `'1'` like others have said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its printing character 1 from the [**ASCII table**](http://www.cdrummond.qc.ca/cegep/informat/professeurs/alain/files/ascii.htm)
 *(making reasonable assumptions about your platform, that you aren't on an EBCDIC platform or something)*

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are assigning 1 (ASCII value of a character)  to `x` . Assign `'1'` to `x`. It will give output `1`.

```
char x = '1'; 
printf("%c\n",x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Characters in C should usually be assigned using characters, not by using ASCII encoding. For example:

```
    char x = 'A';
    printf("%c\n", x);
```

Will print the character 'A' on  the terminal. By giving the character the ASCII index of 1, you're assigning it the START OF HEADING character (SOH). If you were looking for 'A' or '1', that would be:

```
   char x = 65; // x = 'A' 
   char y = '1'; // y = '1'
```

But like I said, this is very awkward and requires ASCII memorization to read, so assigning numbers is very bad practice.

You can find an ASCII table at: http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want as output. If you think that your code is giving something weird as output, you certainly want '1' as output. And for that, you should replace your statement

```
    char x = 1;
```

to

```
    char x = '1';
```

Thats it! Your problem would be solved!